# How to use a channel as mask in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, layers

Is there a way in Photoshop to use a channel (for example red or Lab luminosity) as a mask for a layer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, two ways I know of:

- Go to the channels palette.
- Select the channel you want.

  [image]
- Ctrl-click (Cmd-Click on a Mac), to copy the channel.
- Then go back to your layer and add your mask

  [image]

or

- create a blank, white mask on your layer
- make sure the mask is selected
- go to Image > Apply Image

  [image]
- select the channel you want from the channel dropdown
- click ok

I use a red mask when doing skin softening, because skin will show up light in the red channel.  I describe this in my answer to this question: [What is the best techinque to smooth skin?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3652/what-is-the-best-techinque-to-smooth-skin)